# Iterating through an array by returning a set of 6 elements in jQuery $.each loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I am iterating through an array of 12 objects, every time I iterate through it by pressing the button under a class of `.more`, I have to return a block of 6 elements and I am confused as to how I can achieve this. This is my code so far:

**HTML**

```html
<template>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="cards">

    </div>

    <div>
      <button class="more btn btn-primary md">See More</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "Home",
};
</script>
```

**JS:**

```js
import $ from 'jquery'

$(document).ready(function () {
    const objects = [
        {
            "title": "Some Title",
            "img": "https://248006.selcdn.ru/main/iblock/791/791d4f7e1811fc18b008e31b047a54a6/3e03093c347a4555d92807d3256f0a7e.png",
            "description": "Some description",
            "link": "Some link"

        },
        {
            "title": "Some Title",
            "img": "https://248006.selcdn.ru/main/iblock/b4e/b4e9551322feee132949ffbd60f05397/aee8267040ae839cb0bf672ab5970bda.png",
            "description": "Some description",
            "link": "Some link"
        },
        {
            "title": "Some Title",
            "img": "https://248006.selcdn.ru/main/iblock/e99/e99743d644ded41e802a1741e832b4b4/77d8a8e4af7fab0a1f84d9a9c6cb48cf.png",
            "description": "Some description",
            "link": "Some link"
        },
        {
            "title": "Some Title",
            "img": "https://248006.selcdn.ru/main/iblock/d05/d05042d4e116ba8ad2c4f29bbb45fa00/69c29b1afc93a6c7423fed01a3ac6c63.jpg",
            "description": "Some description",
            "link": "Some link"
        },
        {
            "title": "Some Title",
            "img": "https://248006.selcdn.ru/main/iblock/252/25299d51a4b47cd7d2b8babeb0658a68/c45aa13e7282b1e9628ffea8ed9dfb20.png",
            "description": "Some description",
            "link": "Some link"
        },
        {
            "title": "Some Title",
            "img": "https://248006.selcdn.ru/main/iblock/3a5/3a5a20dc5c2df3fe6db3ccd499880eb3/61a581933fe2134ecec44e432d7c6f31.png",
            "description": "Some description",
            "link": "Some link"

        },
        {
            "title": "Another Title",
            "img": "https://248006.selcdn.ru/main/iblock/3a5/3a5a20dc5c2df3fe6db3ccd499880eb3/61a581933fe2134ecec44e432d7c6f31.png",
            "description": "Some description",
            "link": "Another link"

        },
        {
            "title": "New Title",
            "img": "https://248006.selcdn.ru/main/iblock/3a5/3a5a20dc5c2df3fe6db3ccd499880eb3/61a581933fe2134ecec44e432d7c6f31.png",
            "description": "Some description",
            "link": "Newer link"

        },
        {
            "title": "New Title",
            "img": "https://248006.selcdn.ru/main/iblock/218/218adba31af31ec25cfd345a94974fa1/e37024d8cbd416964bbe075ea53ecf8f.png",
            "description": "Some description",
            "link": "Newer link"

        },
        {
            "title": "Lorem",
            "img": "https://248006.selcdn.ru/main/iblock/3a5/3a5a20dc5c2df3fe6db3ccd499880eb3/61a581933fe2134ecec44e432d7c6f31.png",
            "description": "Some description",
            "link": "Newer link"

        },
        {
            "title": "Some title",
            "img": "https://248006.selcdn.ru/main/iblock/282/282214a04b2c627ecf552efdb71c38f7/c0dbdfdcf4c2901099855f157324f21d.png",
            "description": "Some description",
            "link": "Newer link"

        },
        {
            "title": "Some title",
            "img": "https://248006.selcdn.ru/main/iblock/a9c/a9c6702dcb9b98c0ae79f68d2801a09b/288c49908d4e0e1a97b528615bdc801a.png",
            "description": "Some description",
            "link": "New link"

        },

    ];
    var i = 0;

    $('.more').on('click', function () {
        $.each(objects, function(index, value){

            $('.cards').append('<div class="card-' + index + '">' + '<img src="">' + '<h4></h4>' + '<p></p>' + '<a href="#">' + '</a>' + '</div>');
            $('.cards .card-' + index + " h4").html('<h4>' + value.title + '</h4>');
            $('.cards .card-' + index + " a").html('<a>' + value.link + '</a>');

            $('.cards .card-' + index + " p").html('<p>' + value.description + '</p>');

            $('.cards .card-' + index + " img").attr("src", value.img);
            objects.slice(i, i + 6);
            
        });
    });
    var arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12];

    for (var z = 0; z < arr.length; z += 4) {
    console.log("Working with: " + arr.slice(z, z + 4));
    }
});
```

I tried implementing a counter of `i`, but every time it returns the same objects without iterating through an array fully. It's kind of hard to explain, excuse my English.

Comment: Slicing an array, _while_ you are currently each-ing over it - that can't be a good idea. You already got the index available inside your loop, so you could simply _do nothing_, if index < x or index > y ... all you have to do is calculate the correct x and y then.

Comment: So essentially I would need to implement a forEach loop to iterate through the keys, or how would you do this? Is there a way of doing this with a $.each loop? I

Comment: No, I meant within your existing each loop. You already _have_ access to the index the item has in the array there - that's the `index` parameter of the callback function.

Comment: so get rid of the  object.slice() and add for(i; i < objects.length; i++) and at the end return index += 5? But this still doesnt return the desired result

Comment: No, I did not say anything about adding a `for` loop either. Count your number of clicks, and based on that, determine with elements you need to show. And then inside your existing `each` loop, just _skip_ the elements with an index that falls out of that range.

Comment: How would I write this out?

Answer (score 0):

First of all do not use this idea on click.

```
$('.cards .card-' + index + " img").attr("src", value.img);
```

On each click the index start from `zero` so you get duplicate `card-1` `card-2` and so on (Mega buggy).

[image]

If you want to add **unique index** class for each card use extra variable (Not related to `index` of `each` function).

```
  let card_index = 1;

  $('.more').on('click', function () {
    $.each(objects.slice(start_at, cursor), function(index, value){
      $('.cards').append('<li class="card-' + card_index++ + '">' + value.title + '</li>');
```

---

**One solution**

```
slice(start, end)
```

Use slice and on [each](https://api.jquery.com/each/) click update the `start` and `end` points (Like "cursor" idea).

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  const objects = [
    {
      "title": "object 1",
    },
    {
      "title": "object 2",
    },
    {
      "title": "object 3",
    },
    {
      "title": "object 4",
    },
    {
      "title": "object 5",
    },
    {
      "title": "object 6",
    },
    {
      "title": "object 7",
    },
    {
      "title": "object 8",
    },
    {
      "title": "object 9",
    },
    {
      "title": "object 10",
    },
    {
      "title": "object 11",
    },
    {
      "title": "object 12",
    },
    {
      "title": "object 13",
    },
    {
      "title": "object 14"
    },
    {
      "title": "object 15"
    }
  ];

  let start_at = 0;
  let cursor = 2; /* how much items to load on each click */
  let steps_size = cursor;
  let card_index = 1;

  $("#steps_size").text(steps_size);

  /* deafult cards */
  function load(){
    $.each(objects.slice(start_at, cursor), function(index, value){
      $('.cards').append('<li class="card card-' + card_index++ + '">' + value.title + '</li>');
    });/* end each */
    /* update cursors */
    start_at = start_at + steps_size;
    cursor = start_at + steps_size;

    /* if no more objects */
    if(start_at > objects.length){
      alert("list ends");
      $("#more").hide();
    }
    console.log("start_at: " + start_at);
    console.log("cursor: " + cursor);  
  }

  load();

  $('.more').on('click', function () {
    $.each(objects.slice(start_at, cursor), function(index, value){
      $('.cards').append('<li class="card card-' + card_index++ + '">' + value.title + '</li>');
    });/* end each */
    /* update cursors */
    start_at = start_at + steps_size;
    cursor = start_at + steps_size;

    /* if no more objects */
    if(start_at > objects.length){
      alert("list ends");
      $("#more").hide();
    }
    console.log("start_at: " + start_at);
    console.log("cursor: " + cursor);  
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <ul class="cards">
  </ul>
<div>
  <button id="more" class="more btn btn-primary md">Load <span id="steps_size"></span> more objects
</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this. I hope the code is self explanatory.
Let me know in the comments for any query

```js
var iteration = 1;
var itemsInIterations = 6;

    $('.more').on('click', function () {
        //Get the start index for this iteration  (It will be 0, 6, 12, 18....)    
        const startFromIndex = (iteration - 1) * itemsInIterations;
        
        //Get the end index for this iteration (It will be 6, 12, 18 ....)
        const endToIndex = iteration * itemsInIterations;
        
        //Get a slice of objects for this iteration
        const iterationObjects = objects.slice(startFromIndex, endToIndex);
        
        $.each(iterationObjects, function(index, value){

            $('.cards').append('<div class="card-' + index + '">' + '<img src="">' + '<h4></h4>' + '<p></p>' + '<a href="#">' + '</a>' + '</div>');
            $('.cards .card-' + index + " h4").html('<h4>' + value.title + '</h4>');
            $('.cards .card-' + index + " a").html('<a>' + value.link + '</a>');

            $('.cards .card-' + index + " p").html('<p>' + value.description + '</p>');

            $('.cards .card-' + index + " img").attr("src", value.img);            
        });
        
        //Increment the iteration by 1 for next iteration
        iteration++;
    });
```